# how to throw an exception in java

Tags: java

I have a loop running for number of records and upon a specific condition, I need to add an errorCode and errorMessage to the output response as below

addErrorMessage(Constants.ZERO_AMPU, msg, infoRow) where the method sets the error code and message.

I have defined user defined exception to throw exception on the same condition so that it does not loop through all the records

```
if (ampu.intValue() == 0){

            def message = "ampu value is zero"

            Constants.addErrorMessage(Constants.ZERO_AMPU, message, tariffOffer)
            Ampu a = new Ampu();
            throw a;
}

class Ampu extends Exception{
        public Ampu(){}
            def message = "ampu value is zero"
            Constants.addErrorMessage(Constants.ZERO_AMPU, message, infoRow)
            return "ampu value is zero";

    }
```

what am I missing in throwing the exception here ?

Comment: Are you sure you have a loop? Did you mean to write `while` instead of `if`?

Comment: "def message" Which language are you writing in?

Comment: I don't think this code is valid in any language.

Comment: is this stuff groovy ?

Comment: Sorry, this is a groovy script and I have implemented it using a user defined exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the return value:

```
public Ampu(){}
        message = "ampu value is zero"
        Constants.addErrorMessage(Constants.ZERO_AMPU, message, infoRow)
}
```

Since an exception is stil an object it should have a valid constructor.

`message` should be defined as a string(but it's already  a field so don't declare it).

Answer (score 0):

I have introduced a new user defined exception as below

```
class Ampu extends Exception{
        public Ampu(String message){
             super(message);
        }
}
```

and invoking it using

```
throw new Ampu("ampu is zero");
```

and caught the exception as below

```
}catch(Ampu a){
        Constants.debug ("Margin Calculator Error: " + a.getMessage())
        if (Constants.DEBUG) ex.printStackTrace()

        if (infoRow)
        {
        println 'in catch of AMPU...coming????'
        def msg = "ampu is zero"
        Constants.addErrorMessage(Constants.ZERO_AMPU, msg, infoRow)
```

This resolved my issue.